# Kotlin webview crash

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview, kotlin, android-view

I'm trying to access a `WebView` from a `Fragment` and kotlin keeps on saying:

```
kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.webkit.WebView
```

I have tried to make it null as default then init it but that does not work either. Any suggestions on how I can make it work?

My code:

```
private lateinit var webView: WebView

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.editor_edit_fragment, container, false)
    webView = view.findViewById(R.id.webview) as WebView

    resumeWebView()

    return view
}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webview" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Looks like `view.findViewById(R.id.webview)` is returning `null`. Are you sure you have a View with that id in `R.layout.editor_edit_fragment`?

Comment: I am completely sure. Just checked

Comment: Did not work to add ?.

Comment: The problem is that `findViewById` is returning `null` for some reason, it's right there in the error. You can assign that to a nullable variable, but that doesn't get you anywhere.

Comment: @alvarlagerlof Please also show your editor_edit_fragment.xml.

Comment: Added xml. Adding both ? does not work either

Comment: This looks completely fine to me and `findViewById` should definitely not return `null`. Can you place a breakpoint on the `webView = ...` line and inspect the `children` field of `view`? Which children does it have?

Comment: It does not crash anymore. But I the webview is completely empty

Comment: An empty webview is normal if you haven't loaded a link yet. Since you're in a fragment, it is sometimes helpful to bind the views in `onCreateView` and then execute further commands in `onViewCreated`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run onCreateView first, then onViewCreated to set up WebView.

```
class FragmentWebview : Fragment() {

    lateinit var contentView: View


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_webview, container, false)
        return contentView

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val webview = contentView.findViewById<WebView>(R.id.myWebview)

        val url = "http://google.com"


        val webSettings = myWebview.settings

        webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webSettings.domStorageEnabled = true


        webview.webViewClient = WebViewClient()

        webview.loadUrl(url)

    }
}
```